# Android Studio assets fonts folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio and I have the following code:

```
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "micra.ttf");
```

Which executes perfectly when my `.ttf` file is under the assets folder. But when I make a folder `assets/fonts`, move the `.ttf` file to that folder and try the following code:

```
Typeface customTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/micra.ttf");
```

The application crashes.

What is the problem here? Should I replace the `/` symbol with something else? My assets folder is under app/src/main.

Comment: "The application crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This well work for me. I used `getActivity()` context to `getAssets()` from that context

```
Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/EntangledPlain.ttf");
```

My folder structure is like this
[image]

Comment: Wow... I added `.this` infront of `.getAssets()` as you showed and it worked! Thank you! Can you explain why it is not workig without `.this`?

Comment: Because we need context of the assets folder, otherwise it dnt know where are our assets folder. If it helps accept the answer.